# If else case for established connection

Tags: linux, bash

How do I modify this test such that if the number of connections to port 1234 is greater than 10 then to execute a command (like an `echo` something)?

```
[[ $(netstat -tan | awk '/:1234/ && /ESTABLISHED/{n++} END {print n+0}') = 2 ]
```

may be just `=10` and if is more will go to `else` ?

```
[[ $(netstat -tan | awk '/:1234/ && /ESTABLISHED/{n++} END {print n+0}') = 10 ]
```

or is there some other way?

This is my full script

```
#!/bin/bash
servers=( "1.1.1.1" "2.2.2.2" "3.3.3.3" )
param=( 1 2 3 )

n=0

for i in "${servers[@]}"; do

ping -c 1 $i > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   snmptrap -v 2c -c public .... ${param[$n]}
fi
let $((n+=1))
done
if [[ $(netstat -tan | awk '/:3708/ && /ESTABLISHED/{n++} END {print n+0}') = 2 ]] ; then
    #echo "conn ok"
snmptrap -v 2c -c public ...
fi
if [[ $(netstat -tan | awk '/:1234/ && /ESTABLISHED/{n++} END {print n+0}') -gt 10 ]] ;   then
#echo "test"
snmptrap -v 2c -c public ...
fi
```

This is the output from running it with `bash -x`

```
++ netstat -na
++ grep :1234
++ grep ESTABLISH
++ wc -l
+ '[' 13 -gt 10 ']'
```

Comment: Hi Goro. I have tried to edit your question to be a bit more clear. If you feel my edit changed your intent, feel free to either roll back (click the "edited ... ago" link above my name, and "roll back" to the desired revision), or even better, **[edit]** further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
if [[ VAR=$(netstat -tan | awk '/:1234/ && /ESTABLISHED/{n++} END {print n+0}') -gt 2 ]]; then echo $VAR; fi
```

[image]

Comment: Same result doesn't echo anything even if there is more than 10..

Comment: Save it on a script and execute it with `bash -x`.

Comment: Yes, with `echo $VAR` is done but in my case after `THEN` I have `snmptrap...` which doesn't work properly.

Comment: In that case, you should modify the question. People can't know what you have in the next line.

Comment: Edited with the script. So in last `IF` if I put `echo "test"` I see it. But if I leave it with `snmptrap -v 2c -c public ...` I don't see anything to change

Comment: Maybe you have to check the `snmptrap` command. Inserting an `echo` is not the reason for your command to fail. Let me insist, run your script with `bash -x your-script.sh`.

Comment: I have updated with the response of `bash -x script`